# Is it worth bothering learning a framework to start a project?

Tags: frameworks

The more I read about frameworks, the more people seem to complain that they're not worth the time to learn.

Is there a specific use-case that I should be aware of that makes frameworks valuable?  Or am I just wasting precious time learning something that I will later on abandon?

EDIT: changed title for clarity.  Oops, sorry.

Comment: add some details.  what kind of framework? what frameworks specifically?  it will completely vary depending on the framework...

Comment: Very vague question. We need details, man!

Comment: In my opinion not specific enough to give you a very good answer. Could you give us more background information? For example learning some small php framework with 5 users is probably not worth the effort, but "boost for c++" on the other site is in most cases worth it, because you can certainly reuse your knowledge later...

Comment: The concept of a "framework" itself seems to be nebulous.  Here, I'll pick one: Ruby on Rails.  Here's another: Django.  Here's a third: Internet Communication Engine.  Here's a fourth: CORBA.  Here's a fifth: .Net 2.0.

Comment: Each of these have different scopes, purposes, but the have a single common factor: they want to reduce your effort when coding something.  So the crux of this is, if you're spending more time coding within the framework than without, then why are we bothering?

Comment: I wouldn't call CORBA a framework, any more than RMI or COM are frameworks.  Ruby on Rails and Django qualify, in my opinion.  They both solve the problem of data-driven, browser-based UI applications.

Comment: I wouldn't call CORBA a protocol either.  They're a framework in the sense that they provide mechanisms and data structures for accomplishing a task that would have otherwise been done through new code.  Which brings the next question - if CORBA isn't a framework, then what is ICE?

Comment: CORBA's IIOP is a protocol, so I'll disagree with that.  The CORBA services (e.g., naming and the rest) are over and above, so I'll agree that it's in-between.  I have neither knowledge of nor experience with ICE, so I can't say.  Frameworks to me are much more problem-specific than CORBA or RMI.  I still don't put them in the same category as Django, Spring, or RoR.  As for your need for assurance, I think the only way to assure yourself is to dig in and do the work.  I wouldn't take it from SO without due diligence, that's for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that when doing a large project, even if you decide to not use a framework to begin with, halfway through the project you will end up writing a mini framework anyway as you reuse functions written for one part of the project for another.

The problem with this though is the mini ad-hoc framework you end up writing will be

- poorly designed
- have basically no documentation
- lacking in features
- Only the people on your team will know how to use it, and learning it will seem like a waste of time as it is only being used on your project
- Difficult to extend unless you know the source code backwards

Using a framework when beginning your project on the other hand will:

- save on all the time you spent writing those utility functions that made up your add-hoc framework
- be well designed
- have lots of documentation
- Many people will know how to use it, other people will be more willing to learn as they will see it will be useful in future projects
- Be very feature complete
- Easy to extend (due to a plugin system) for people, even if they don't know the source code for it well
- be continuously updated, without any effort on your part

I think for any medium sized or larger project, using a framework (if a good one is available) is a huge time saver, as long as you are given a enough time to actually learn how to use it. I often think a lot of the criticisms of frameworks come from people who were never given the time to learn how to use it properly. Trying to use a framework then is quite painful, as you will end up constantly using hacks to get around non-existant problems, problems you wouldn't even have if you knew the framework properly.

Answer (score 2):

We make extensive use of [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx) in our projects.  People who complain too much about frameworks are the types that want to build everything from scratch.  Having a solid framework that handles the aspects of what you are doing (exception handling, logging, caching, data access, policy injection, unit testing, dependency injection, monitoring and instrumentation, encryption, etc.) are extremely valuable.

A good framework will let you concentrate on your business issues rather than the aspects of your application that are orthogonal to what you are actually trying to accomplish.  Also, it is an absolute waste of time to write those things yourself, when outstanding frameworks with thousands of man-hours in development and QA and possibly hundreds of thousands of production hours are out there.  I can justify 100% the business case for using EntLib.

Comment: You mean, as you said in your first line, a library and not a framework. A framework is a tool that "frames" the way you have to code, a tool which try to **force** some way of doing things on you.

Comment: Intersting, I consider EntLib to be a framework in that it provides a great deal of scaffolding and plumbing for your application that you don't have to write yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning it may seem quicker to start without a framework.

I compare it to loading a dishwasher.  You'll have to do the work the work sooner, or later.  Either you load the dishes in an organized way beforehand, or take the time to sort it out when taking it out.

As you build, deploy, extend your project, you will increasingly wish for / start building in ways to increase code re-use, structure, and framework.

See if there's a framework that you can start quickly building with.  I think it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

What good are frameworks?

If you choose the right one, it's solid code that you don't have to write.  It's better than the stuff you'd do on your own.  It's written by developers who are more talented than you are, tested by a wider audience than your code is, has a longer history of fixed bugs than your application has, and has a longer, better track record than anything you've written.

Your application is better off if you can find a framework that meets all those criteria.

Frameworks aren't equal.  It's important to choose wisely and well.  If you pick a good one, you won't abandon it later on.

That's why I've been using Spring for the last five years.

I would recommend learning the framework before you use it on a live project.  You're likely to do a poor job with a framework that you don't know - which will be a convenient excuse to blame the framework.  Get some training and do a dry run on something significant before you turn it loose on your first live project.  Get a mentor or leader to guide you through your first effort.

On second reading, I'd say it sounds like you've made up your mind.  No one is forcing you to use a framework.  By all means, do roll your own.  Develop enough experience to decide for yourself.

But if there are teammates, employers, or clients affected by the decision make sure that they have a full understanding of the opportunity cost of rolling your own.

Comment: Frameworks are also written by developers that don't know your requirements, goals, etc. For large projects you'd probably be better off rolling your own framework, but it all depends on the project, of course.

Comment: No, that's not the way frameworks are written.  The people who write them have to have very deep knowledge of the problem they're trying to solve.  Anyone who's ever written one will tell you that it takes one, two, or three tries before you see the commonality of a problem well enough to write something that manages "Don't call us, we'll call you" successfully.

Comment: I haven't made up my mind.  I've been looking at ICE for some time as part of a small project that I would like to start (always the back burner, always pressed for time), but before I devote months (realtime, probably 20 hours) of reading and experimentation, I want an assurance that it's worth the investment.